# Redirect after signing in after being redirected from users/edit in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

If unauthenticated users attempt to access `users/edit` , devise redirects them to `users/sign_in`. This is good. However, after successful signing in, I wish the user to be redirected back to `users/edit`. How is this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you overriden the `after_sign_in_path_for` method? Check out the wiki about [How To: redirect to a specific page on successful sign in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

Anyway, AFAIK, if you haven't overriden this method, the default behaviour is redirect user to the [last stored location](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/store_location.rb#L16), 'users/edit' in that case. Check out the content of `stored_location_for` on your application before user is signed in.

Comment: Yes... I was overriding after_sign_in_path. By saving previous path in `user_return_to` I didn't have to override it anymore, and everything works fine now. Also I've now learned that I could have used `stored_location_for(resource)` in the overridden method and it would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the question as `how do I redirect back after sign in`, where the answer would be thus:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
  end
end
```